# Can't start Apache in XAMPP

Tags: apache, xampp

I have a problem when I'm trying to start the Apache module in XAMPP localhost. When I click start, I get this:

> 3:26:33 PM [Apache] Problem detected! 
>   3:26:33 PM [Apache] Port 80 in use by "C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\Skype.exe"  with PID 1680! 
>   3:26:33 PM [Apache] Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free! 
>   3:26:33 PM [Apache] You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application 
>   3:26:33 PM [Apache] or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a different port 
>   3:26:33 PM [Apache] Problem detected! 
>   3:26:33 PM [Apache] Port 443 in use by "C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\Skype.exe" with PID 1680! 
>   3:26:33 PM [Apache] Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free! 
>   3:26:33 PM [Apache] You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application 
>   3:26:33 PM [Apache] or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a  
> different port
>   3:26:33 PM [Apache] Attempting to start Apache app... 
>   3:26:33 PM [Apache] Status change detected: running

Answer (score 3):

Change the port of Skype or disable Skype on startup.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21182512/how-to-stop-vmware-port-error-of-443-on-xampp-control-panel-v3-2-1/21182630#21182630), your question may be solved as follows.

Here is the solution step-by-step:

1. Open up file *httpd-ssl.conf* in `path2xampp\apache\conf\extra`
2. Look for the line *"Listen 443"*
3. Change the port number to anything you want. I use 4430. For example, *"Listen 4430"*.
4. Replace every "443" string in that file with "4430".
5. Save the file.

Answer (score 1):

You have to disable port 80 in [Skype's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skype) connection settings, restart Skype, and then you can use your Apache server.

Comment: @HossamRamadan then you have to open localhost:1337

Answer (score 0):

First open:

Xamp → *Config* → *apache (httpd.config)* → change port: 8080

Then

> ServerName localhost:8080

Then save. Again click

*Config* → httpd-ssl.config* → *Listen 4433* → *<VirtualHost _default_:4433>*

Then save and now press start

Comment: What is the context of "Xamp"? Is it a GUI application? A menu command? A configuration file? A web interface? Do you mean [XAMPP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XAMPP)?

Comment: Is it *"[XAMPP Control Panel](https://www.atechtown.com/xampp-control-panel/)"*?

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, you must stop all running processes referring to Skype in [Task Manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Manager) or by cmd:

```
tasklist
```

then

```
Taskkill /PID 1680 /F
```

After that, go to the `xampp` folder, run apache-stop.exe and then run `apache-start.exe`.

That executed cmd command and its result are helpful to get what error you actually have.

Answer (score -1):

Just disable VMware services.

It works for me.

Comment: How exactly can that be done (respond by [editing your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/40332610/edit), not here in comments)?