# How to stop VMware port error of 443 on XAMPP Control Panel v3.2.1

Tags: php, apache, xampp

When I run XAMPP Control Panel v3.2.1 I get this error:

```
07:37:24  [Apache]  Problem detected!
07:37:24  [Apache]  Port 443 in use by ""C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\VMware Workstation\vmware-hostd.exe" -u "C:\ProgramData\VMware\hostd\config.xml"" with PID 2148!
07:37:24  [Apache]  Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
07:37:24  [Apache]  You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
07:37:24  [Apache]  or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
```

I could not fix it myself. Getting help soon will be thankful.

Answer (score 152, accepted):

Here is the solution step-by-step:

1. Open up `httpd-ssl.conf` in `path2xampp\apache\conf\extra`
2. Look for the line `Listen 443`
3. Change port number to anything you want. I use `4430`. ex. `Listen 4430`.
4. Replace every `443` string in that file with `4430`.
5. Save the file.
6. and, Finally restart your apache.
7. done.

Comment: same as above i m getting new error on my localhost
__localhost/xampp HTTPS (SSL) DEACTIVATED__
Any how your answer is helped more

Comment: Found the answer. In the file "httpd-ssl.conf", under the comment "SSL Virtual Host Context" pages on port 443 meaning https is looked up under different document root. simply change the document root to the same one and problem is fixed.

Comment: This is more a patch than a fix. When running VMWare, like @zorus40k below said, disabling sharing (and changing the port) did the absolute trick.

Comment: Nice! I could not run Apache with XAMPP anymore since I installed Vmware Player. Your answer fixed the problem.

Comment: Nailed it, quickly!

Comment: No need to use SSL on XAMPP cause it's purpose is testing (development server)

Comment: In addition to the above, you need to add the following setting: xampp->config->service and port settings->apache->ssl port set 4430

Answer (score 216):

It's easier to change the port in VMware Workstation:

1. Edit > Preferences;
2. Shared VMs tab;
3. Disable;
4. Change port;
5. Enable.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Done.

Comment: This is the solution everyone should follow. Thank you! And in case anyone is interested, Skype can use ports 80 and 443 as well. If you have Skype installed and running, make sure to uncheck the 'Use port 80 and 443 for additional incoming connections.' option in Options > Advanced > Connection.

Comment: Yes, This is the proper solution, instead of making apache to listen on other https port

Comment: If the "Enable/Disable Sharing" button is not clickable, check your VMs settings and set Folder sharing to "No" in every VM. Then change the port and re-enable everything.

Comment: There is no 'Shared VMs' section in Edit -> Preferences with VMware Workstation 16 anymore. Any idea on how to change the port anyway?

Comment: I prefer this solution over the accepted one. Since you only need to manipulate the one that causes the problem in the first place.

Answer (score 10):

Run vmware as administrator in windows or as root in linux. Then ctrl+P to open preferences. then on shared vms. You can see a port number 443 by default. This is conflicting with apache that is why it is not starting. Change it to some other value say 8443. Then try to start apache it will run.

Answer (score 8):

Just go to vmvare edit->preferences->shared vms. Click on change settings and disable sharing.click on OK.xampp will work fine.

Answer (score 4):

Connecting to shared virtual machines

Connection to VMware Workstation Server (the shared virtual machines) is administered by the VMware Host Agent service. The service uses TCP ports 80 and 443. This service is also used by other VMware products, including VMware Server and vSphere, and provides additional capabilities.
Configuring shared virtual machines

With the Shared VMs Workstation preferences, you can disable/enable the server, assign a different port for connecting, and change the Shared VMs directory.

To access the Shared VMs Workstation preferences:

```
Go to Edit > Preferences.
Click the Shared VMs tab.
```

Answer (score 3):

Open VMware Workstation > Edit > Prefrences > Shared VMS > Change port 433 > 4330 > save.

Follow the process Showed in the Following video :
https://youtu.be/DYj7qIgwV2M

Answer (score 1):

Here is the solution:
You use Ctrl+Alt+Delete, open **task manager** and switch to tab **services** find VMWareHostd and right click to chose **StopService**. You can start xampp without error

Comment: I m working on vmware currently. I cant stop that :(

Comment: Find this file: xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-ssl.conf and go to line 41,80,83 replace port 443 to another port and restart xampp. Try this. It will work.

Comment: yes now that error not comes is fixed. Getting new error localhost/xampp  **   HTTPS (SSL) DEACTIVATED ** @user3198763

Comment: Open the file xampp/apache/conf/httpd.conf in an editor and search for the line: #LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so remove the hashmark, save the file and re-start the apache. The webserver should now start with xampp's basic/default ssl confguration; good enough for testing but you might want to read up a bit more about mod_ssl in the apache documentation.

Answer (score 1):

On Xampp edit apache config

1. Click Apache 'config'
2. Select 'httpd-ssl.conf'
3. Look for 'Listen 443',
   change it to 'Listen 4430'

Answer (score 0):

Say you let vmware use port 443, and use another ssl port in XAMPP Apache (httpd-ssl.conf) :

The red error will keep popping in XAMPP Control Panel.
You also need to change the port in the XAMPP Control Panel configuration :

In XAMPP Control Panel, click the "Config" button (top-left).
Then click "Service and Port Settings". There you can set the ports to match the ports used by Apache.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no `Shared VMs` tab, you can edit the config manually.

1. Go to `C:\ProgramData\VMware\hostd`, and open `proxy.xml` with a text editor.
2. At the top, there should be `<httpsPort>443</httpsPort>`. Change it to `-1`.
3. Kill the process using Powershell:

```
Stop-Process -Id <PROCESS_ID>
```

Use the process ID provided in XAMPP's Control Panel's log.

You should be able to start Apache now.

Answer (score -2):

Run XAMPP Control Panel as Administrator if using Windows 7 or more. Windows may block access to ports if not accessed by adminstrator user.