# port 443 is used by http.exe, Apache, Xampp

Tags: php, apache, xampp

I have problems with Xampp. It does not execute my php scripts. When I open php file the php code appears in the browser.
When I open Xampp it has these red lines:

```
Apache Service detected with wrong path
11:53:25 PM  [Apache]   Change XAMPP Apache settings or
11:53:25 PM  [Apache]   Uninstall/disable the other service manually first
11:53:25 PM  [Apache]   Found Path: ERROR: Not Able To Open Service Manager
11:53:25 PM  [Apache]   Expected Path: "c:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe" -k runservice
11:53:25 PM  [Apache]   Problem detected!
11:53:25 PM  [Apache]   Port 443 in use by "httpd.exe"!
11:53:25 PM  [Apache]   Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
11:53:25 PM  [Apache]   You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
11:53:25 PM  [Apache]   or reconfigure Apache to listen on a different port
```

Please help me? What can I do?please....Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error in running apache services from XAMPP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14284271/error-in-running-apache-services-from-xampp)

Comment: I cant stop appache...it says to me : access violation ataddress 005ABEFE in module 'xampp-control.exe' . Read of adress 00000042...Please can you hel me

Answer (score 6):

with refer to this [Q](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21182512/how-to-stop-vmware-port-error-of-443-on-xampp-control-panel-v3-2-1/21182630#21182630)

or With refer to this [page](http://el.web.id/how-to-solve-xampp-problem-port-80-443-in-use-by-skype-470):

The easiest way to solve this XAMPP problem is shutdown your Skype, and restart your XAMPP Control Panel. But that is not a smart solution.

So how to solve this port in use issue? In Skype **Options: [Connection]** , there is a check-box labelled ***Use port 80 and 443 as alternatives for incoming connections***.

This is the root problem, so simply clear / unchecked it and save. You may need to restart Skype.

Restart your XAMPP Control Panel, and the error message is now gone! Try to start Apache, and succeeded.

What if the port is not used by Skype, but by other applications such as **TeamViewer** or any other things? If so, then XAMPP have to use another port.

***How to change Apache default port in XAMPP?***

- From XAMPP Control Panel, under Apache, click the Config button, and
  select the Apache (**httpd.conf**).
- Inside the httpd.conf file, find line that says

  ```
  Listen 80
  ```
- And change the 80 into any number / port you want. In this example
  I’m using port 8080.

  ```
  Listen 8080
  ```
- Still from the httpd.conf file, find another line that says

  ```
  ServerName localhost:80
  ```
- And change 80 to 8080.

  ```
  ServerName localhost:8080
  ```
- Next step, still from XAMPP Control Panel, under Apache, click the
  Config button again, but this time select the Apache
  (httpd-ssl.conf). Inside the httpd-ssl.conf file, find line that says

  ```
  Listen 443
  ```
- And change the 443 into any number / port you want. I’ll using 4433
  as the new port number.

  ```
  Listen 4433
  ```
- Still from the httpd-ssl.conf file, find another line that says

  ```
  <VirtualHost _default_:443>

  ServerName localhost:443
  ```
- And change 443 to 4433.

  ```
  <VirtualHost _default_:4433>

  ServerName localhost:4433
  ```

***Remember*** to save **httpd.conf** file and **httpd-ssl.conf** after you make some changes.

Now it’s time to fire-up our Apache in XAMPP Control Panel. If your doing good on editing those files, you should see that Apache is running and the port number has changed to **8080** and **4433**.

Comment: well I did this and my Apache is running. But it still shows the "Port 443 in use" error.

Comment: @DebsmitaPaul  --> you might run another apache service on your system, make sure you stop all other apache services. `TASKKILL /F /IM httpd.exe /T` this command with terminating your httpd.exe

Comment: It turns out the problem was with VMWare Workstation. It was using the port 443, I changed it by going to **Edit** > **Prefences** > **Shared VMS**, then **Disabled Sharing** and changed the port to 4433. It worked. Thank you for your help @EniGma. :)

Answer (score 2):

If you use Windows Go to **Task Manager** and **Stop "httpd.exe"**

Comment: i go there...but I cant find httpd.exe  . What can I do

Answer (score 0):

The errors/warnings suggest that you already have another Apache installed as a service, on port 443.